# How can I make pseudo function and function prime for SciPy fmin_l_bfgs_b?

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy

I want to use `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b` to find the minimum of a cost function.

To do this, I want to create an instance of `one_batch` (the code of `one_batch` is given below) in the first place to specify the batch of training examples and those parameters that are not included in the loss function but necessary to calculate the loss.

Because the module `loss_calc` is designed to return the loss and loss prime at the same time, I'm facing with the problem of separating the loss function and loss function prime for `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b`.

As you can see from the code of `one_batch`, given a batch of traning examples, the `[loss, dloss/dParameters]` will be calculated in parallel for each of the examples. I don't want to do the exact same calculations twice for `get_loss` and `get_loss_prime`.

So how can I design the methods `get_loss` and `get_loss_prime`, so that I only need to do parallel calculation once?

Here is the code of `one_batch`

```
from calculator import loss_calc

class one_batch:

    def __init__(self, 
                 auxiliary_model_parameters, 
                 batch_example):

        # auxiliary_model_parameters are parameters need to specify 
        # the loss calculator but are not included in the loss function.

        self.auxiliary_model_parameters = auxiliary_model_parameters 
        self.batch_example = batch_example

    def parallel(self, func, args):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        result = pool.map(func, args)
        return result 

    def one_example(self, example):
        temp_instance = loss_calc(self.auxiliary_model_parameters, 
                                  self.model_vector)
        loss, dloss = temp_instance(example).calculate()
        return [loss, dloss]

    def main(self, model_vector):
        self.model_vector = model_vector

        # model_vector and auxiliary_model_parameters are necessary 
        # for creating an instance of loss function calculator 

        result_list = parallel(self.one_example, 
                               self.batch_examples)

        # result_list is a list of sublists, each sublist is 
        # [loss, dloss/dParameter] for each training example 

   def get_loss(self):
       ?

   def get_loss_prime(self):
       ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an objective function that returns both function value directly as an input to `fmin_l_bfgs_b`:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin_l_bfgs_b
import numpy as np

def obj_fun(x):
    fx = 2*x**2 + 2*x + 1
    grad = np.array([4*x + 2])
    return fx, grad

fmin_l_bfgs_b(obj_fun, x0=[12])
```

> (array([-0.5]),  array([0.5]),  {'grad': array([[-3.55271368e-15]]),
>   'task': b'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL',
>   'funcalls': 4,   'nit': 2,   'warnflag': 0})